# Conversion on new and returning visitors

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce, metrics

I was looking to do a quick comparison of conversion rates between new and returning visitors using Google Analytics. I can seem to get this working fine by using the dimensions "date" and "visitor type", when adding the metric "avg time on site" or anything else really into that mix. However when adding the metric "transactions", all the transactions get added to the "new visitor" dimension.

Not sure if this is a bug in my set-up, something I'm doing wrong, or maybe even something that simply doesn't work in GA. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't there a report that shows time to purchase by days and visits? Showing how many days it takes a user to purchase 1 day 2 days (returning) etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason could be that your tracking code has an error, and all transactions is registered in a new GA cookie. If your transactions is registered in a new cookie, then GA treats it as a new visitor. It's long shot, but on the top of my head, this is the only thing I think of.

Use Firebug or Google Chromes developer tools to see which cookies get set.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Emil, indeed there were issues in the set-up done by our external agency. I tried the same reports on some other ecom sites I have access to and they worked perfectly. So for the other people here having this issue: check your set-up!